# Como faço para converter um certificado .PFX para .PEM?

Tags: vb.net, certificado-digital

Eu exportei um arquivo `.pfx` do meu certificado A3. Como faço para convertê-lo para `.pem`. Em VB.Net se possível.

Comment: Acredito não ser possível fazer isso em .Net sem o uso de uma biblioteca externa. Em todo o caso, você pode usar o OpenSSL (executando ele como um comando externo).

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Vinicius!
Eu consegui fazer isso, mas saberia me dizer se tem como eu usar o VB.net e interagir com o OpenSSL? 
Por exemplo chamar ele no meu projeto e passar os parâmetros via programação ?
Obrigado

Comment: Não vou escrever uma resposta pois não vou saber te dar muito mais detalhes, a não ser que você diga que é suficiente, claro! Você pode chamar o executável `openssl.exe` e passar os parâmetros diretamente para ele, ou utilizar `PInvoke` para chamar comandos da `libopenssl` (acho que o nome é esse) de modo a não executar um programa externo, mas eu não sei quais comandos são estes. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Entendi, Vinicius!!
Muito obrigado por ora, vou fazer uns testes.
Abraços!

Comment: pelo vb.net execute em command line... Não uso vb.net mas acredito que exista função para executar linhas de comando. Um exemplo, no PHP existe função exec(). No google, procure como "vb.net execute command line".

Answer (score 3):

O jeito mais fácil acho que é com o binário do OpenSSL, geralmente para linux, mas que também tem versão pra Windows:

O instalador pode ser obtido aqui: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html (link direto: http://slproweb.com/download/Win32OpenSSL_Light-1_0_1j.exe ), ou em alguma biblioteca de software como 'cygwin', por exemplo, se você tiver familiaridade com isso.

O comando para a conversão é:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in c:\caminho\do\certificado\de\origem.pfx -out c:\caminho\do\arquivo\de\destino.pem -nodes
```

Ao digitar este comando, será solicitada a senha utilizada para proteger o arquivo .pfx original, para que ele seja descriptografado. Este comando irá gerar um certificado DESPROTEGIDO (sem senha), que é adequado para utilização em aplicações automatizadas (por exemplo, servidores web).

Fonte:

```
http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX106028
```